# JavaFX Random TextField colors

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create random filling in TextFields when i press the button. I troubled at button's method. I already done filling single color but i need it creates randomly every pressing.

```
TextField textField1;
public Button encoloura;

 public void encoloura(ActionEvent event) {
/// textField1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(random, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));


    }
```

Comment: Give us the method for passing a color

Comment: Show us the code you have (The important part/only the part necessary for us to understand your approach/the desired behaviour) and also improve the problem description. Should this fill in the colors as text (e.g. `"red", "blue", "#ffaa88"` or something like that) or should the color be assigned as background color? BTW I'd really like to know why this question was considered worthy of an upvote in it's current state...

Comment: TextField textField1;
    public Button encoloura;

     public void encoloura(ActionEvent event) {
    /// textField1.setBackground(new Background(new     BackgroundFill(random, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));


        }

Comment: How do you create `random`(= the color passed to the `BackgroundFill` constructor)? (I guess the `encoloura` method is called from the `onAction` event of the button(?))

Comment: yes encoloura is onAction